# How can I add labels and text boxes programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

How can I add labels and text boxes in iphone programmatically? 
How can I set frame for the labels and text boxes?

Answer (score 17):

The following code creates a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` and adds them to the view controllers view. Add this code in the `loadView` method or somewhere in your view controller.

```
// Create Label
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 40)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myLabel setText:@"Hi Label"];
[[self view] addSubview:myLabel];
[myLabel release];

// Create Text Field
UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200, 40)];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myTextField setText:@"Hi Text Field"];
[[self view] addSubview:myTextField];
[myTextField release];
```

You can also set other properties using the setter methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 29, 40)];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 29, 40)];
label.text = @"Custom Label";
[label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
[self.view addSubview:m_label];
```